# Indexes in oracle:

Tags: oracle

Which of the below would be the best way to create an Index, so that my query gives faster results?

My query is:

```
select emp_name,emp_last_name, salary 
from employees_table 
where salary <=2000;

1. create index emp_index on employees_table (salary);

2. create index emp_index on employees_table (emp_name,emp_last_name,salary);
```

Comment: And what is your opinion, which index is better in your opinion and why?

Comment: In my opinion, it would be the second one, because if index is made only on salary column the sqlengine would be able to access salary field only, but to access other data, it has to search the table.

Comment: good answer. From these two idexes number 2 is better than 1-st. Such the index is known as [covering index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index). However there is still a better option (3) for this concrete query --> `create index emp_index on employees_table (salary, emp_name,emp_last_name);`. Note that it is amost the same as #2, only the order of columns differs ... Do you know why it is better ?

Comment: Either #1 or #2 could be better, there is no "best" way when it comes to choosing indexes.

Answer (score 1):

In principle `create index emp_index on employees_table (emp_name,emp_last_name,salary);` would be the better one, because for your query Oracle has to read only the index but not any table data.

However, this means you create a separate index for each particular query which is certainly an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 index Oracle may will be select table access full, if disctinct values in firsts columns of index to much, Oracle give you Table access full, if distinct values in first columns of index not much then you give index skip scan.

For first index you will see “index range scan” + “table access by rowid”....

but for both index’s - if sql returns >5-7% rows then Oracle maybe want to use “Table access full”...

All depends on your data in Table and count return rows